# get all object from 1 list of 1 list by stream in java 8?

Tags: java, spring

I have 2 classes, this:

```
public class TimeCardResponse {
   private String login;
   List<TimeCardDetail> timeCardDetails;
}
```

and this:

```
public TimeCardDetail(String workingDay, Float workingTime) {
    this.workingDay = workingDay;
    this.workingTime = workingTime;
}
    input : a List<TimeCardResponse>
```

I want to get all `workingDay` of class `TimeCardDetail` in a `List<String>` and using `Stream` in Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> workingDays  = a.stream().map(TimeCardResponse::getTimeCardDetails)
                .filter(x-> Objects::nonNull)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .map(TimeCardDetail::getWorkingDay).collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some a `getWorkingDay` method:

```
List<String> workDays = timeCardDetails.stream()
                                       .map(TimeCardDetail::getWorkingDay)
                                       .filter(Objects::nonNull)    //filter out null values
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which will return a `List<String>` of the work days of the time Cards